# Exclude / Block PDF Printer

Tags: java, c#, pdf, printing

I wanna know if it's possible to recognize printer in Java/C# as a pdf printer and block them.

The main reason behind this is, that i have a printing software with pictures which include copyrights. Within the web its easy for me to safe these copyrights with watermarks etc, but also the user is able to print out of the application.

If an user print the image to a pdf printer, he could cut the image out of the pdf f.e. . 
Because in the printing result, the customer dont want a watermark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that this is possible by only checking a property. What you can do is first to get all the printers by

[PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx)

```
for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++){
    pkInstalledPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i];
}
```

after that you can write out the printer settings with [PrintSystemObject.PropertiesCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemobject.propertiescollection(v=vs.110).aspx) or directly the processor name with the [PrintProcessorProperty Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.indexedproperties.printprocessorproperty(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then you need to look at the property if you can specify the PDF Printers with any of these properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the print processor of the printer and see if it's a known PDF print processor.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printsystemobject.propertiescollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx